# Issue adding separate single pole dimmer switch next to existing 3 way connection

Tags: wiring, switch, dimmer-switch, multiway-switch

As the title suggests, I’m having an issue when attempting to add a single pole dimmer switch (one of these guys: https://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/0301882.pdf) next to an existing 3-way light switch connection.

The wife recently asked if we can ditch the lamps in exchange for recessed lighting. I had an existing 3 way light switch box that I expanded and will put a 2 gang old-work box in to accommodate the new light switch that will control the recessed lighting.

There were 3 wires coming into the previous box.

1. Traveler wires (R/B(capped)/W/G)
2. Power from previous outlet in circuit (B/W/G)
3. wire going to next outlet in circuit (B/W/G)

In picture form:

[image: Wires coming in]

As you can see, I've attempted to wire in the dimmer. There are 4 wires there (RW [capped for single pole]/R/B/G). I've connected all the neutrals and grounds in the box. Added 2 jumpers to the 2 black wires connected in the box and connected one jumper to the existing 3-way switch and one jumper to the black wire of the new dimmer. The red wire of the new dimmer, I've connected to the black coming from the new recessed lighting. The result - the 3-way operates as expected (since nothing changed there) but nothing for the recessed lighting, none of them turn on. While I haven't gotten a chance yet, will do this afternoon, to check to see if each of the lights in the series are actually getting power, I wanted to check with this community if the wiring shown here is correct and troubleshooting should be focused on the lights themselves.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Did you try the recessed lights **with the 3-way in different positions?** Depending which 3-way it is in its circuit, the black wire associated might be switched. You might be able to get constant hot from your other cable, depending where that goes. In short, you might have misidentified the function of some cables in this box... Trivial check for "switch weirdness" would be to connect the new lights black to the switch black (taking the new switch out of the circuit entirely.)

Comment: Thanks for the response Ecnerwal! DEFINITELY possible the cables are misidentified…I simply went to the panel and followed the wires to the box. Now, If by “in different positions” you mean just flipping the 3-way switch, yes I did try that thinking maybe I made a mistake and made the new lights dependent on the 3-way switch position. But that did not change the result. I will try the “connect new light black to switch black” idea to see if that yields light…I assume then the new black AND red wires would just be tied in together to the existing black connections in the box.

Comment: I find it odd that the "traveler black" is capped, (I initially misread that as being a whole disused second traveler cable for a previous switch.) Hmmm.

Comment: Ecnerwal, that did remind me. We had the house rewired a few years ago and there WAS a second 3-way switch in this area that connected to the lights in the next room over. We had that removed from this box. I suppose it’s possible that traveler black is leftover from that switch.